# ASP.NET MVC3 Changes to models

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, nuget

For anyone familiar with Python/Django and the South migration module, I'm trying to find the asp.net MVC3 version if it exists.

What I'm trying to accomplish is create an entity, insert data, and in the future change my model and have the database incorporate the new data appropriately. I want to avoid manual SQL changes.

Does this exist in C# and is it reliable? I've read a bit about the DBInitializers, I'm not really okay with deleting all my data, test data or not, every time an entity needs an update.

Third party package is an acceptable solution (preferably from NuGet) if it has an active user base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a good combo ORM and migrations tool. I'm not super familiar with Django, but I've done some work with Rails, and at a glance South looks a bit like ActiveRecord + rake. Does that sound accurate?

The best ORM I've worked with for .NET is EntityFramework 4.1 (i.e. - EF Code First) which is available [here](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/EntityFramework). It just happens to be the most downloaded package on NuGet.

Microsoft has released a migrations package for EF that's [also available on NuGet](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/EntityFramework.SqlMigrations). Scott Haneslman [blogged](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EntityFrameworkCodeFirstMigrationsAlphaNuGetPackageOfTheWeek10.aspx) about it a little while back.

You could also look into [NHibernate](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/NHibernate) as some people swear by it. I've personally never used it, but I've heard great things.

Hopefully that gets you started in the right direction.

**// Edit**

Doing a little bit more digging around on NuGet, I stumbled on [Fluent Migrator](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/FluentMigrator) which looks promising. Perhaps a better alternative to the EF Migrations package for now...

Comment: The version 2 you linked is actually deprecated, but you pointed me to the Version 3 of Code First Migrations, the project looks really new so that's a little scary. 8 Days ago they released version 3 which isn't reverse compatible with version 2! Talk about a nightmare...
Here is the link in case someone else is doing a similar question:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/21/code-first-migrations-alpha-3-released.aspx

I'll leave the post open for another day or two in case there are better alternatives (It's too new and untested to be reliable!).

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't surprise me. I was going off memory from that Scott Hanselman post, but as of his blog, it was in Alpha. I just remembered thinking, "Hmmm... .NET is finally going to get a rake equivalent". Hopefully it'll mature nicely, but I'm not expecting to see a 1.0 until .NET 4.5 comes out late this year or early next year.

Comment: Migrations is still in early preview release.  Don't expect to be able to use it in production anytime soon.

Comment: Fluent Migrator and the EF Migration package seem to be the only real options right now for ASP.NET, it'd be nice for their core ideas to be combined, thanks for the edit.